# hiking trails near by Salzburg and Linz

Tags: hiking, austria, mountains, salzburg

I'm looking for a one day hiking trails in north-west Austria near by Salzburg and Linz. Can you recommend me some not easy trails, which go uphill but without climbing, 15-20km distance, I will take food/water for one day, but if there is a hut it is ok for me. I found [this](http://www.outdooractive.com/de/bergtour/schladming-dachstein/rund-um-die-steirische-kalkspitze/1483018/) and I'm looking for similar.

Comment: What are easy trails for you? It's kinda hard to judge individual skills from behind a keyboard. I'm afraid this question is opinion-based.

Comment: I like hiking in Tatra Mountains (Orla Perć) and I'm looking for something similar. Ease for me are for example bieszczady mountains.

Comment: Linz is wonderful! You can hike along the Danube downstream to Melk. Or upstream to Passau, which Alexander Humboldt called one of the 7 most beautiful cities in the world. Or just cross the river and hike into the hills. It's great.